# Calculating diversity indices across sites in R

Tags: r, for-loop, vegan

I have a dataframe(df)as follows:

```
Year PlotNo HabitatType Sp1 Sp2 Sp3 Sp4
2000   1       GH        0   1   2   3
1988   3       KL        2   3   4   5
```

where, `Sp` stands for Species and its columns represent abundance value.

I'm trying to find the Simpson's diversity for each row in the dataframe. I have attempted the following for loop:

```
require(vegan)
y <- for(i in 1:nrow(df)) {
row <- df[i,4:50] #Assuming 50 columns
diversity(row, "simp")
}
```

However, I keep running into an error as follows :

> Error in sum(x) : invalid 'type' (character) of argument

Any ideas on how to correct this error? Or any alternate way of going about this?

Comment: as a side note: don't call a data.frame `df`. That is the name of a function in R and will lead to confusing error messges in case of a syntax error.

Comment: And could you make your example reproducible? Without that we are left guessing what is going wrong exactly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`diversity` indeed needs numerical data, and this may be your problem. What do you get from `sum(df[,4:50])`?

Another issue is that you do not need a `for()` loop: when given a data frame or a matrix, `diversity` will calculate the index for each row (or column if you set argument `MARGIN = 2`). So `diversity(df[,4:50])` should do, provided that your data are numeric.

Comment: Aha, I did not realise that. I thought I'd have to loop diversity across each row to get the result. That solved it!

Answer (score 1):

We can use:

```
library(data.table)
mydf <- setDF(mydf)
res <- mydf[, div := diversity(mydf[, 4:7], 'simp')]
```

This add a colum `div` with the result of the `diversity` function for each row.

Answer (score 0):

The `diversity` function can only deal with numerical data. Probably, `df[i,4:50]` contain non-numeric elements. My guess is that some of the columns are `character` or `factor`. However, without a reproducible example I can't confirm that this is the case.

Comment: I checked this using str(df). The year and plot_id are int, plot_type is a factor and the rest of the columns are num, as should be. When I do summary(df) all the columns from 4:50 have a mean/median etc. Also, I looked at only between 4:7 now and the output says NULL

Comment: The output of your original command will always be `NULL`, since you have `y <- for() {}` and `for()`returns `NULL`. If you want to collect the result in a loop, you must do assignment within the loop: `y <- numeric(nrow(df)); for(i in 1:nrow(df)) {...; y[i] <- diversity(row, "simp")}`. However, with `diversity` you don't need `for()`.